# Patterns for managing user profiles in nodejs/react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Not talking about authentication -- there are plenty of options for that like passport or auth0. But in node and/or React, what do we do with the rest of the user profile and related user data we collect? Things like application preferences or links to a users social profiles or phone number, etc etc.

Is the only option just to store that user profile data in a database like its 1995 or is there a handy module/library/tool people recommend that makes it easier?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete solution to use React and Node then you may take alook at the MERN stack:

- http://mern.io/

Of course you don't need to use Express and Mongo to use Node and React together but this can be a good start.

You can also find more examples here:

- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/725
- https://vladimirponomarev.com/blog/authentication-in-react-apps-creating-components
- https://vladimirponomarev.com/blog/authentication-in-react-apps-jwt
- https://github.com/vladimirponomarev/authentication-in-react-apps

Comment: Thanks. Seems like you are recommending storing the user profile data in a DB as opposed to there being some kind of Passport-like module? (Which is the essence of my question)